# How to use Tasker broadcasts in Macrodroid?

Tags: macrodroid

I have this app , [forcedoze](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.suyashsrijan.forcedoze) which enforces better *doze*
for extra battery saving. I want to enable / disable it on schedule for which I see broadcast for Tasker

```
com.suyashsrijan.forcedoze.ENABLE_FORCEDOZE
```

(Broadcast values required : None)

And a similar one with `DISABLE`

How do I use this in Macrodroid? Guess I need to use intents but am clueless on this, not having used it and it looks complicated - am not sure what to fill in multiple options ( if my guess is correct )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution requires sending the intents with superuser (root) privilege and unfortunately, the *Send Intent* action in MacroDroid does not permit that. So I've used the *Script* action of MacroDroid as a workaround.

Sending a broadcast (it is universal, not Tasker specific) alone would not do anything here. Using the *logcat*, I noticed that the app starts the service named *ForceDozeService* and then issues the relevant broadcast.

**Script (*en.sh*) to enable the ForceDoze:**

```
#!/system/bin/sh

su -c 'am startservice com.suyashsrijan.forcedoze/.ForceDozeService' 
su -c 'am broadcast -a com.suyashsrijan.forcedoze.ENABLE_FORCEDOZE -n com.suyashsrijan.forcedoze/.EnableForceDozeService'
```

**Script (*ds.sh*) to disable the ForceDoze:**

```
#!/system/bin/sh

su -c 'am stopservice com.suyashsrijan.forcedoze/.ForceDozeService' 
su -c 'am broadcast -a com.suyashsrijan.forcedoze.DISABLE_FORCEDOZE -n com.suyashsrijan.forcedoze/.DisableForceDozeService'
```

Use the action *Script* in Macrodroid as:

```
sh FILE_PATH      // such as /sdcard/en.sh
```

That should work.

Comment: With mere logic. you can actually reduce this to one single script and reduce the redundancy I added in superuser privilege. I would have done that myself, but I'm short on time now.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and prompt revert. Will try this later. and revert if  any issues - though I am sure it would work. Thanks again